# How do i get the ember-concurrency ajax-throttling example to work in my dev environment?

Tags: ember.js, ember-concurrency

My question is, what do i need to fix so that my implementation of the ember-concurrency Ajax Throttling [example](http://ember-concurrency.com/docs/examples/ajax-throttling) works as expected. Specifically, in my implementation no log entries are displayed (as they are on the example page), and the console.log statement that i added in the `loopingAjaxTask` inner function is not executed nor is the console.log statement in the task. I have copied the example nearly verbatim with the only changes being that i've added in those console.log statements.

The line 'looping Ajax task outer function' is written to the console 8 times as expected, but the 'looping Ajax task inner function' is never written to the console log. The 'Hello World' text from the component is written to the page.

I am using ember 4.8 and ember-concurrency 2.3.7.

Here's the template where i've included the AjaxThrottling component.

*app/templates/example.hbs*

```
{{page-title "Example"}}
<p>Here's where the log entries should appear</p>
<AjaxThrottling />
{{outlet}}
```

*app/components/ajax-throttling.hbs*

```
<div>
    hello world
  <ul>
    {{#each this.logs as |log|}}
      <li style={{color log.color}} {{! template-lint-disable no-inline-styles }}>{{log.message}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

*and here is component's js page*

```
import Component from '@glimmer/component';
import { enqueueTask, task, timeout } from 'ember-concurrency';

function loopingAjaxTask(id, color) {
    console.log('looping Ajax task outer function');
    return function* () {
        console.log('looping Ajax task inner function');
        while (true) {
        this.log(color, `Task ${id}: making AJAX request`);
        yield this.ajaxTask.perform();
        this.log(color, `Task ${id}: Done, sleeping.`);
        yield timeout(2000);
      }
    };
  }

export default class AjaxThrottlingComponent extends Component {

    tagName = '';
    logs = [];
  
    ajaxTask = enqueueTask({ maxConcurrency: 3 }, async () => {
      // simulate slow AJAX
      console.log('inside the task')
      await timeout(2000 + 2000 * Math.random());
      return {};
    });
  
    @task({ on: 'init' }) task0 = loopingAjaxTask(0, '#0000FF');
    @task({ on: 'init' }) task1 = loopingAjaxTask(1, '#8A2BE2');
    @task({ on: 'init' }) task2 = loopingAjaxTask(2, '#A52A2A');
    @task({ on: 'init' }) task3 = loopingAjaxTask(3, '#DC143C');
    @task({ on: 'init' }) task4 = loopingAjaxTask(4, '#20B2AA');
    @task({ on: 'init' }) task5 = loopingAjaxTask(5, '#FF1493');
    @task({ on: 'init' }) task6 = loopingAjaxTask(6, '#228B22');
    @task({ on: 'init' }) task7 = loopingAjaxTask(7, '#DAA520');
  
    log(color, message) {
      let logs = this.logs;
      logs.push({ color, message });
      this.set('logs', logs.slice(-7));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this same question on the Ember discussion board as well and got an [answer](https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/ember-concurrency-ajax-throttling-example-not-working-in-my-dev-environment/19843/4). The gist of the answer is that the documentation for ember-concurrency hasn't been fully updated for the newer versions of Ember. After making some changes to account for the modern versions of Ember, the code worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I see that constructor is missing. There should be a constructor in your glimmer component to start off.
After that, you can call your ajax tasks.

Edit : Oh, My bad sorry, I see you've already found an answer.